# I am doing an assignment for college. My Prolog program has 1 syntax error C150. How do I debug the syntax and then query the knowledge base?

Tags: syntax, prolog

Hello

```
How do you query prolog? I also keep getting 1 syntax error.
```

Thank you

Honora Day

```
predicates.
    wife : -female(Y).
    daughter : -female(Y).
    son : -male (X).
    wife (Mum). :-female(Y).
wife (Kydd). :-female(Y).
wife (Elizabeth). :-female(Y) parents (George, Mum).
    wife (Sarah). :-female(Y).
    wife (Anne). :-female(Y)  parents (Phillip, Elizabeth).
wife (Diana). :-female(Y) parents (Spencer, Kydd).
daughter (Zara). :-female(Y) parents (Mark, Anne).
daughter (Beatrice). :-female(Y) parents (Andrew, Sarah).
    son (Charles). :-male(X)  parents (Phillip, Anne).
    son (Andrew). :-male(X)  parents (Phillip, Elizabeth) .
    son (Edward). :-male(X) parents (Phillip, Elizabeth) .
son (William). :-male(X) parents (Charles, Diane).
son (Harry). :-male(X) parents (Charles, Diane).
    son (Peter). :-male(X)  parents (Mark, Anne).
    son (Eugenie). :-male(X) parents (Andrew, Sarah).
    brother(X, Y). :- male (X).
    parents (Pa, Ma, X).
    parents (Pa, Ma, Y).
    wife (Mum).
    wife (Kydd).
    wife (Elizabeth).
   wife (Sarah).
   wife (Anne).
   wife (Diana).
   daughter (Zara).
   daughter (Beatrice).
   son (Charles).
   son (Andrew).
   son (Edward).
   son (William).
   son (Harry).
   son (Peter).
   son (Eugenie).

   goal
```

r)  Test your Prolog program by asking it the following questions. Note, in some cases, it may be impossible to avoid getting the same answer more than once for a query. i) Who is Sarah’s husband? 
ii) Who are Elizabeth’s grandchildren? iii) Who are Zara’s great-grandparents? iv) Who are Diana’s sisters-in-law? v) Who are Beatrice’s uncles? 
Include a printout that shows your query and the program’s responses (you may simply copy this from SWI-Prolog’s main window).

Comment: Wh-what kind of Prolog is this? That's neither SWI nor PDC.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Predicate calculus but according to my little knowledge, your predicates are giving you a answer for first question like question is  i) Who is Sarah’s husband? and in your predicates there is :-female(Y) parents (Andrew, Sarah). son (Charles).  which giving info about Charles parents that are Andrew and Sarah. then Sarah will be wife of Andrew and Andrew will be husband.
Hope that this may help you for further questions

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1153801) question where it is explained how to format your code on SO.

Since we cannot really work with the code you specified, let me just give you a very small example of what your assignment consists of. From there you should be able to figure out what you should be changing.

We consider the following Prolog facts:

```
parent(bill,grandpa_bills).    % Grandpa_bills is the father of Bill
parent(billy_the_kid,bill).    % Bill is the father of billy_the_kid
```

(Note that we don't write the names with capital letters, since Prolog uses capitalised words for variable names.)

Subsequently we can define the concept of grandparent. A grandparent is someone who was children, and those children have children of their own as well. We can write this very easily:

```
grandparent(X,GrandParent) :-
    parent(X,Parent),                 % X has a parent
    parent(Parent,GrandParent).       % and that parent also has a parent
```

Now we can ask Prolog:

```
?- grandparent(jezus,Y).
   false                          % There is no fact present about jezus

?- grandparent(X,Y).
   X = billy_the_kid,
   Y = grandpa_bills
```

In the second query, we illustrate the power of Prolog's unification. We ask Prolog to find us every X and every Y for which the body of grandparent/2 succeeds. In this case, this is only for billy_the_kid and grandpa_bills, but when you expand your set of facts and add more people, this query will return all results (separately) for which grandparent/2 succeeds.

For further information, have a look at [this](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) tutorial.